# Understanding Adverbs

Tags: adverbs

I was trying to understand adverbs. I came across an explanation for which I need further clarity. I'm not sure if I can post links to other sites but if I can let me know and I'll post the source.

Here it is:

"If I ask you to talk very loudly, then very is the adverb: it describes how you are supposed to talk."

My question is what is 'loudly' in this context? And why isn't 'very loudly' the adverb?

Thanks.

Source: https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/adverb

Comment: Yes, it is always preferable that you post a relevant link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as ‘the’ adverb: any utterance may contain as many adverbs as your hearer is willing to listen to.

In your example, *very* is an adverb modifying *loudly*; *loudly* is also an adverb, and the adverb phrase *very loudly* modifies *talk*.

Comment: Thanks, that really helps clarify it. I suppose they were trying to keep it simple but it left me confused.